# comment charactres loading at top of magento page

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

on my Magento 1.6.2.0 front page I am getting /**/ at the top of my page. Seems to be before the page content load at http://nilandsplace.com. I can see it in firebug, but have no way to know where it comes from. Firebug shows

```
<head>
<body class=" ig-404tosearch-index-index cms-home" style="position: relative; min-height: 100%; top: 0px;">
<span id="BuySafeSealSpan" style="display: inline; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; top: auto; right: auto; left: 0px; z-index: 10001; background-color: transparent; height: auto; width: auto;">
/*
<script type="text/javascript">
*/
<meta content="EB5B8B2562CC109C0058726E01C0AFC1" name="msvalidate.01">
<meta content="azPLjb6T1pIRdUuZPmIGr7HV3p982Yaa1TGQKOjMe0E" name="google-site-verification">
<script type="text/javascript">
```

But it should look like this

```
<head>
<body class=" ig-404tosearch-index-index cms-home" style="position: relative; min-height: 100%; top: 0px;">
<span id="BuySafeSealSpan" style="display: inline; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px none; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; top: auto; right: auto; left: 0px; z-index: 10001; background-color: transparent; height: auto; width: auto;">
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="livezilla_tracking" style="display:none">
<script type="text/javascript">
<noscript><img src="http://chat.nilandsplace.com/server.php?request=track&amp;output=nojcrpt&amp;fbpos=12&amp;fbml=0&amp;fbmt=0&amp;fbmr=0&amp;fbmb=0&amp;fbw=32&amp;fbh=112" width="0" height="0" style="visibility:hidden;" alt=""></noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="https://stat.dealtime.com/ROI/ROI2.js" type="text/javascript">
<div class="wrapper">
```

The class=" ig-404tosearch-index-index cms-home" should be between the

```
<body></body>
```

tags and the
    
and what follows should be between

```
<head></head>
```

tags
Some how in removing and old Google translate script in my template files I introduced the

```
/*
<script type="text/javascript">
*/
```

But I can't find it. I have used file comparison to my local back up copy and can't find the Dif file difference. I have a local Apache2 server on my home computer with all the same setup. but my localhost does not have the load error?
I have been through Magento: /app, /core, /default (template files), /design, /js, /lib, /modules, /include and /skin and I am running out of files. I don't save /var/cache or session to files. I have cleared APC and eAccelerator and swapped in my online database to localhost and not found the error.

Comment: commenting in html look like `<!-- -->`

Comment: you also appear to not be closing your `<script>` tags (they are not self closing and so require `</script>` closing tags

Comment: I do not know how to make a script, so have no idea what script is missing a closing tag? All my scripts are from extensions on Magento connect